# Return a value in a nested JSON array, using Alamofire and Swift

Tags: json, swift, multidimensional-array, alamofire, swifty-json

Super new to swift, JSON, and pretty all coding so I apologize in advance if this question is redundant to others on the site or I am missing something simple here.

I am looking to return the value of "text" ("1.7 mi") associated with "distance" in the "elements" array in the JSON code below:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "30 Rockefeller Plaza, New York, NY 10112, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "352 7th Ave, New York, NY 10001, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1.7 mi",
                  "value" : 2729
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "15 mins",
                  "value" : 887
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I retrieved the JSON data using Alamofire and the Google DistanceMatrix (see my code below), but am having trouble parsing the data to isolate what I need. I know the code below isn't close to what I need, but am unsure as to how to proceed.

```
func distanceMatrix(startLocation: String, endLocation: String) {
        let myOrigin = startLocationTFText
        let myDestination = destinationLocationTFText

        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=\(myOrigin)&destinations=\(myDestination)&key=API_Key

        let encodedUrl = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

        AF.request(encodedUrl!).responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request as Any)
            print(response.response as Any)
            print(response.data as Any)
            print(response.result as Any)

            let json = JSON(response.data as Any)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you must explore the Codable protocol with Amlofire. There is an awesome blog on it : https://medium.com/@AladinWay/write-a-networking-layer-in-swift-4-using-alamofire-5-and-codable-part-2-perform-request-and-b5c7ee2e012d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Decodable` to get the desired result.

```
struct RootResponse: Decodable {

   let destinationAddresses, originAddresses: [String]
   let rows: [Rows]
   let status: String
}

struct Rows: Decodable {

  let elements: [Elements]
}

struct Elements: Decodable {

  let distance, duration: Details
  let status: String
}

struct Details: Decodable {
   let text, value: String
}
```

This will be your model file and once you have added it then you can go back to your function and use it as:

```
func distanceMatrix(startLocation: String, endLocation: String) {
    let myOrigin = startLocationTFText
    let myDestination = destinationLocationTFText

    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=\(myOrigin)&destinations=\(myDestination)&key=API_Key"

    let encodedUrl = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    AF.request(encodedUrl!).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request as Any)
        print(response.response as Any)
        print(response.data as Any)
        print(response.result as Any)

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        guard let json = try? decoder.decode(RootResponse.self, from: response.data) else { print("Unable to parse JSON"); return }

        print(json)
        print(json.rows.first?.elements.first?.distance.value) // This is how you can get the value, but it will be better to safely unwrap them and I have also used first? to get the first object but this is an array and you can always use a for loop for further purpose
}
```

Comment: @LittleRocketMan Welcome!